# Convert markdown code block markers to criticMarkup syntax

Tags: sed, markdown

I need to convert multiple markdown code blocks to markdown comment blocks using sed. I want to replace the tags but not the text. (my markdown editor has bad support for comments).

I have:

````
```
Foo
More foo
Even more foo
```
````

I need to convert this to something like

```
{>>
Foo
More foo
Even more foo
<<}
```

i.e. syntax used in [CriticMarkup](http://criticmarkup.com/).

**EDIT**: My method. I first replaced all 2nd ocurances with `>>}`, then in the new file, replaced all 1st occuranges with `{>>`.

For the first step, I used Perl:

```
perl -e '$count = 0; s/\`\`\`/(++$count % 2 == 0)?">>}":$&/ge;' oldfile.md > newfile.md
```

to replace every second backtick, using [this method](https://backreference.org/2012/08/22/replace-every-nth-occurrence/).

Then I followed by a simple sed:

```
sed -i 's/\`\`\`/{>>/g' newfile.md
```

but backticks are all still there.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed '/```/{s//{>>/;:a;n;s//<<}/;Ta}' file
````

Match a line containing ```` ``` ````.

Replace that line by `{>>`.

Read/print following lines.

When another line matches the same regexp, replace it by `<<}`.

N.B. `T` branches when the last substitution fails. It is the dual of `t`.

See [here](https://asciinema.org/a/sS3oSGtSyFMuSNw9VhB3GDIcc) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

````
awk '/```/{f=!f; $0 = f ? "{>>" : "<<}"} 1'
````

- ```` /```/ ```` match three backticks anywhere in the input line. You can also use ```` $0 == "```" ```` to match complete line having three backticks
- `f=!f` by default, uninitialized variables in `awk` are empty in string context and zero in numeric context. Here, you'll get `f=1` the first time, `f=0` next time and so on
- `$0 = f ? "{>>" : "<<}"` change the input line to desired syntax based on `f` being true or false
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0` (the input record)